# Truth value of these two propositions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $P(x, y)$ be the proposition $x^2 = y$, where $x$ and $y$ are in the universe of integers.

Determine the truth value of each of the following propositions.

1. $\forall x \exists y P(x, y)$
2. $\exists y \forall x P(x, y)$

I don't get how to do these two. So I believe it reads as
"For all instances of $x$, and there exists $y P(x,y)$."

Does this mean there is only one instance of $y$? Therefore the statement is false because there are possibly endless instances of $x$ and they can't all equal $y$ when squared?

Comment: I have edited your post to use MathJax.  Can you please have a look at it and make sure that I didn't break anything?  i.e. please make sure that I haven't made any edits that change the question you asking.  Also, what is $c$?

Answer (score 1):

**For the first one:** $\forall x\exists yP(x,y) $ means that for any integer $x$ we can find an integer $y$ such that $y=x^2$. Is this true? Sure, since $x$ is given, we just square it, and that is our value for $y$.

**For the second one:** $\exists y\forall xP(x,y)$ means that there is some integer $y$ such that for all integers $x$, we have $y=x^2$. Is this true? Of course not. Take any integer $y$, then $y=x^2$ has at most two solutions for $x$, so it certainly doesn't hold for all integers $x$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now. :)